# Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 shows many errors in the IDE, but compilation is OK?

Tags: android-studio-2.2

i updated Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1, with oracle JDK 8u91.

in the IDE, many errors are shown, such as: unused import (gray underline), cannot find reference (red characters), etc. but the compilation to APK is ok...

anyone any ideas?

Comment: same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338186/android-studio-2-2-preview1-showing-error

Comment: the projects shows and compiles fine with AS 2.1.1 and JDK 7u79.

Comment: true.. even with java 8 it compiles fine... just IDE change and you run into problems.