# Android Studio 2.2 preview1 errors

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

So i'm trying to use Android Studio 2.2 preview-1 in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I'm using **gradle-2.10** and **gradle-plugin 2.2.0-alpha1** along with **openJDK-8**.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
```

First the **studio.sh** didn't run and i found the solution to change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`. Voila --it starts properly.

But in **build.gradle** files, warning is shown--

```
'dependencies' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'
```

and its not finding imported class from library project(includes a jar only).
Please someone help me out.

Comment: Can you share the entire Gradle file, please? You might be missing the `apply plugin`

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133601/buildtypes-cannot-be-applied-to-groovy-lang-closure

Comment: @cricket_007 everything works perfect with Studio 2.1.1. nothing is missing.

Comment: @Haven i use that configuration. Not working.

Comment: same here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336621/android-studio-2-2-preview-1-shows-many-errors-in-the-ide-but-compilation-is-ok

Comment: @McArthorLee so report bug? but others seems to be fine working with Studio 2.2 preview 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only fix that I found for this is, every time I open a project, I go to Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Gradle, change to "use local gradle distribution", click apply then click "use default gradle wrapper" and ok.

This should fix, but its quite annoying to do this everytime.

Comment: I'm glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

It Looks like a problem of version 2.10 of the wrapper version on gradle.

After reading around people's workaround like

- "invalidate cache and restart"
- delete .gradle file in the project and re-open it
- etc etc

I just try for fun to install a standalone version of gradle since I'd always used only the wrapper version that cames with android studio.

And with it there is any error and any warning.

For anyone who wanna try (I'm a mac's user):

- install gradle (by homebrew is fine and pretty easy) **brew install gradle**
- tell to AS to use that one instead the wrapper version **preference -> build, Execution, Deveployment -> Gradle -> use local gradle distribution**

if you install it by homebrew like me the correct path will be: **/usr/local/Cellar/gradle/x.yy/libexec**
where x.yy it suppose to be 2.11 (that is the last version provide by brew even if the lastest version released is 2.13)

---

I've realised just now that the steps above doens't fix the definitly. Each time you re-open the project the problem came again and again.
It's annoying but changing betwen use of "wrapper"/"regular gradle" take the warning away.
But this means also that isn't a problem o the gradle as I'd assumed at the beginning.

...let's wait a permanent fix ^^

Comment: Thanks for help but i've tried it all already but nothing works on Ubuntu... and no workaround required for Mac as it works fine on my Apple machine.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed in Android Studio 2.2 preview 2 (download from [this page](http://tools.android.com/download/studio/builds/2-2-preview-2)).

> Disabled a couple of Groovy inspections that reported incorrect errors in build.gradle files

From the [changelog](http://tools.android.com/recent).