# dependencies cannot be applied to groovy.lang.Closure (Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1)

Tags: android, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-2.2

#### Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1 brought back this error. :/

```
'dependencies' cannot be applied to '(groovy.lang.Closure)'
This inspection reports assignments with incompatible types
Lines 44-45 changed
```

Has anyone run into the same problem?

[image]

## Update - 05/29/2016

The bug has been fixed in Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2

Comment: which line is `41` and `42`.

Comment: @Ironman those lines means nothing... 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'

This information is about the last lines that I've changed. Now is showing 55-72.

Comment: but in `screenshot` display error that place see the `screenshot`.

Comment: @Ironman yep, i saw.. The app keeps working and compiling fine, without errors.. But I've this warning in build.gradle (app) and (project) too. Both in dependencies.

Comment: now do this In Android Studio select: `File\Settings\Build, Execution, Deployment\Build tools\Gradle` and `Mark:` `Use default gradle wrapper (default)` . it will solve your problem.

Comment: now solve your problem ?

Comment: I've done it before and is already as default, and didn't work.

apparently I'm not the only one:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210670
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210494

Comment: That's just a warning isn't it? It all istil works doesn't it?

Comment: @tim_yates yep.. so far no problems

Comment: Think it can just be ignored, i see the same in intellij

Comment: same question already asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338186/android-studio-2-2-preview1-showing-error

Answer (score 0):

The only fix that I found for this is, every time I open a project, I go to Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Gradle, change to "use local gradle distribution", click apply then click "use default gradle wrapper" and ok.

Comment: I've done it before and is already as default, and didn't work. Apparently in Android Studio 2.2 Preview 2 was back to normal.